# How do I show that $Arg(z)$ is continuous on the complex plane except at the non positive real line?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I show that $Arg(z)$ is continuous on the complex plane except at the non positive real line?

I know that

$$Arg(z) =
\begin{cases}
\sin^{-1}\frac{y}{|z|},  & \text{if $x\ge0$ } \\
\pi- \sin^{-1}\frac{y}{|z|}, & \text{if $x<0$ and $y\ge0$} \\
-\pi- \sin^{-1}\frac{y}{|z|}, & \text{if $x<0$ and $y<0$}
\end{cases} $$

but how do I use this definition to show continuity everywhere except at the non positive real line?

Answer (score 0):

If $x>0$ then $\operatorname{Arg}(x)=0$; if $x<0$, then $\operatorname{Arg}(x)=\pi$. This shows discontinuity at $(0,0)$.

If $x<0$, compute $\lim_{y\to0^\pm}\operatorname{Arg}(x+y\,i)$ and find that $\operatorname{Arg}$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Everywhere else is easy to show continuity.